# What would Typical Adaptations for Life be on a Gas Giant's Habitable Moon?

Tags: science-based, xenobiology, moons

Okay, this question may seem too broad, but bear with me.

On Damarian, the largest moon of the gas giant Checuti, there are no continents larger than the Americas (Both North and South America) in area, but there are many of them all across Damarian. Most of the biggest of these are about 3,200 km apart, and there is a massive ocean on one side.

I'm fairly sure that tsunamis would be a big problem, especially if they spawn on the ocean side of Damarian. I'm also sure that the fact that Damarian is tidally locked with Checuti (Due to the fact that Checuti is a gas giant denser than Jupiter, and Damarian's just a wee little Earth ball. 50% larger than Earth...) would affect the adaptations.

***Damarian Factoids:***

- Due to how Damarian is locked with Checuti, you can see Checuti from the westernmost of the landmasses, and the eastern side of the ocean (Think I'll call is the Oruchkan Ocean, or just Oruchkan) gets a similar view. Standing in a specific spot on Damarian's surface would give you a view of whatever part of Checuti Damarian was passing over, without it being hidden by horizon. During what would count as an eclipse if you're viewing from Checuti, people with a view of Checuti can sometimes see the shadow of Damarian passing over Checuti.
- Damarian has a magnetic liquid that freezes well above temperatures that Earth-like life can survive, but that operates just like normal Earth crust at habitable temperatures. This liquid provides Damarian's magnetic field, which is needed due to Damarian being too far from Checuti to really have much of Checuti's magnetic field helping out.
- Damarian has moderately extreme temperature variation, depending on where it is in its orbit around Checuti. If it's on the closer side to Kenser of its orbit (That is, it's more to the inner edge of the habitable system), it gets warmer globally, while, on the other side of the year, it gets colder globally. Unfortunately, this might not be too relevant, because of the next factoid:
- Damarian's day/night cycle is 50 Earth hours, which also happens to be its orbit time around Checuti. Its year time is 384 Earth days. Thus, Damarian has a year of about 185 days.

Okay, I'm not asking anyone to build a new ecosystem, but I'd like to know general things that native life would possess.

***Ideas:***

- Obviously, a sleep/wake cycle twice as long as Earth life, due to longer day/night cycle.
- Possibly a behavior that makes land life retreat from the heat about 12 hours 30 minutes into day, due to midday being blazing hot, and a similar behavior 12 hours 30 minutes into night, due to it being possibly very cold.

These are only two adaptations I though of, but I believe someone else might have other thoughts or insight.

NOTE: By typical adaptations, I mean adaptations nearly all animals would most likely have. Also, Damarian could be split into 4 parts: The Oruchkan ocean on the Checuti side, the Oruchkan on the Kenser side, the land on the Checuti side, and the land on the Kenser side.

Comment: Please remember the [help/dont-ask] says, "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where … your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers." Also, since the one and only data point we have for life on a planet is Earth, it's a bit odd to ask what a "typical" adaptation would be.

Comment: It's very hard for a planet or a moon to be a single, homogeneous environment. There is no "typical adaptation". Take a shark and an extremophilus. They are both adapted to live on Earth, yet they are completely different.

Comment: The general things found in life in a rainforest environment looks very little like the general things found in life living at the deepest depths of the ocean, which itself has few things in common to life adapted to the extreme conditions of a desert; and those are on planet Earth alone. When it comes to gas giants, all we know about how life would develop there is that it'd probably be nothing like what we have on earth [due to how inhospitable the conditions are](https://www.missionjuno.swri.edu/jupiter/atmosphere?show=hs_jupiter_atmosphere_story_is-there-life-on-jupiter).